# Can an analytic function defined on a maximal torus be extended analytically to all the Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Let $G$ be a compact group and $T$ a maximal torus on $G$. Suppose $f$ is an analytic function defined on $T$. Is there an analytic function $F$ on $G$ whose restriction agrees with $f$ on $T$?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be consequence of the paper

Cartan, Henri: Variétés analytiques réelles et variétés analytiques complexes. Bull. Soc. Math. France 85 1957 77–99

Cartan shows more generally (see sections 6 and 7), that a real analytic function on a real analytic submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ can be extended to a real analytic function on all of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: By the way, this old paper by H. Cartan is available online here http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=BSMF_1957__85__77_0

Comment: The link is now http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1957__85__77_0/